# How to install packages (like auto-complete) for Emacs 23.1.1 with no internet?

Tags: emacs, install.packages

My work computer has Emacs 23.1.1 and using git to clone repos is not allowed. I tried to install `package.el` manually and add elpa and melpa sources, but I got the error "Failed to download 'melpa' archive".

Basically, I want to install some popular packages like powerline, smartparens, evil and auto-complete and I tried manually, however, for each of them, I encountered some errors, all having something to do with missing some function definitions.

So, I would like to ask that without the ability to upgrade Emacs, is there any way that I can install those packages I mentioned above manually? Or do those packages have a version that could be compatible with Emacs 23.1.1?

Comment: Some packages will not work without a newer version of Emacs as certain functions, variables, macros may not exist or may have been substantially changed in newer releases.  Support for specific problems you encounter will not be readily forthcoming when contacting package maintainers and/or posting requests for assistance on-line for the same reasons ....  That being said, Google for a package and see if it is hosted on-line such as Github, MELPA, etc.  Download and put them into your `load-path`.  Basically, every package is likely to be problematic and require time to make it work ... :(

Comment: IIRC (and I'm not certain that I do) the `package.el` which is available for Emacs 23 is not compatible with the package archives used for Emacs 24+, in which case you would not be able to use the likes of GNU ELPA and MELPA.  This may explain the error you were seeing.

Comment: Packages with a history dating back to Emacs 23 will certainly have had past revisions which are compatible with 23.1.1 (and some later packages may also have been written with backwards-compatibility in mind), but the current versions may require more recent versions of Emacs. Where there is a version control repository for the package (or some other history of releases), you should look through that history to find a compatible version.